# Is it a binary operation?

Tags: functions, relations, binary-operations

[image]

I am having problems with problem (i) shown in the image above.

> Examine which of the following is a binary operation:
>   (i) $a*b=\frac{a+b}{2}; a,b\in\mathbb{N}$

Now since $a$ and $b$ are natural numbers, they belong to the set $\mathbb{N}$. However the operation $a*b=(a+b)/2$ may not be a binary operation because for one (either $a$ or $b$) odd and the other even, the operation $a*b$ will not give a natural number.  Hence the operation should not be a binary operation in $\mathbb{N}$.  But the book has written that it is.  So what is correct?

Comment: But the site said that i can't upload image because my reputation is below 10. @Joel_Reyes_Noche

Comment: I have added it.

Comment: are you claiming that `3[odd natural number]*2[even natural number]=6[even natural number]` isn't a natural number?

Comment: @nonchip, I think the OP is claiming that $(3+2)/2=5/2$ is not a natural number.  Note that the operation $*$ is not multiplication.

Comment: (3+2)÷2 is not a natural number. @nonchip

Comment: The usual definition is: "a binary operation on a set is a calculation that combines two elements of the set (called operands) to produce another element of the set."  Is this the same as the definition in your book?

Comment: Yes. But their answer doesn't match their definition.

Comment: yes, `(3+2)/2` isn't, but `(3*2)` is, and you wrote: "the operation a*b will not give a natural number". did you mean "must not"? and "can not" where you wrote "must not" before?

Comment: 3*2 is a symbol for binary operation on 3 and 2. And i have changed 'must not' to 'may not'. @nonchip

Comment: @nonchip, you say that "(3+2)/2 isn't [a natural number], but (3*2) is [a natural number]."  The latter statement is incorrect.  The asterisk here does not denote multiplication.

Comment: @JoelReyesNoche oh it doesn't? then my fault, just out of interest: what does it denote though?

Comment: @nonchip it denotes a generic operation, in this case, it is defined as the arithmetic average of the two operands.

Comment: @JoelReyesNoche ooh so it assigns the operation's definition, not just denotes equality of 2 actual operations?

Comment: @nonchip, yes..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your reasoning seems to be correct and the book is in error.

Comment: note this might also be intentional (as a question), to trick people into proving it to see if they realize their disprove is actually correct. but the solution still is in error then. also the book is missing the actual proof in the solution, which is always a bad thing.